# SELECT * FROM db1 WHERE db1.table.value = db2.table.value

Tags: mysql, sql, reactjs, database, express

I'm working with mySQL db and trying to display the correct data for the user. In order to do that I check if the data that I call from one backend is equal to username from another backend like so

```
SELECT * FROM db1 WHERE db1.table.value = db2.table.value
```

Names of databases are A and B.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `A.onboardings`
     , `B.loginsystem` 
 WHERE onboardings.sales_email = loginsystem.username
```

The problem is I get an error `A.A.onboardings doesn't exists` and `A.B.loginsystem doesn't exist` pls help :(

Answer (score 0):

You must use this form - from A onboardings

Comment: but A and B are 2 different schemas, I can't access schema B it's not in A

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the backticks in the right pace, or else mysql things your table is called `A.onboardings`

As seen bleow the needs to be around the database and the table name

And the use of aliases helps to keep even in big queries a good overview and yu have to write less

```
"SELECT * FROM `A`.`onboardings` a1,`B`.`loginsystem` b1 WHERE a1.sales_email = b1.username"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one( Change the query according to your DB name, table, and matching column name)

```
SELECT * FROM mydatabase1.tblUsers INNER JOIN mydatabase2.tblUsers ON mydatabase1.tblUsers.UserID = mydatabase2.tblUsers.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
`A.onboardings`
```

is not the same as

```
 A.onboardings
```

The first is a table reference where there table name has a period in it.  The second is for the `onboardings` table in database `A`.

In addition, you should be using `JOIN`!!!

```
SELECT *
FROM A.onboardings o JOIN
     B.loginsystem ls
     ON o.sales_email = ls.username;
```

If you feel compelled to escape the identifies -- which I do *not* recommend -- then:

```
SELECT *
FROM `A`.`onboardings` o JOIN
     `B`.`loginsystem` ls
     ON o.sales_email = ls.username;
```